# Grab elements inside parentheses

Tags: python, regex

How can I grab the elements inside the parentheses and put them in a file?

me (I) 
you (You)
him (He)
her (She)

Thanks in advance,
Adia

Comment: Adia, please refrain from making comments by creating an answer.  At 50 rep, you can leave actual comments like this one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import re

txt = 'me (I) you (You) him (He) her (She)'
words = re.findall('\((.+?)\)', txt)

# words returns: ['I', 'You', 'He', 'She']
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.write('\n'.join(words))

# file 'filename.txt' contains now:

I
You
He
She
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/)?

```
from pyparsing import Word, alphas

text = "me (I) you (You) him (He) her (She)"

parser = "(" + Word(alphas).setResultsName("value") + ")"

out = open("myfile.txt", "w")
for token, start, end in parser.scanString(text):
    print >>out, token.value
```

Output:

```
I
You
He
She
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a few simple string manipulation will do

```
>>> s="me (I) you (You) him (He) her (She)"
>>> for i in s.split(")"):
...     if "(" in i:
...        print i.split("(")[-1]
...
I
You
He
She
```